# Why do I have to insert USB storage twice to mount it?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, usb, kde, usb-drive

Often, I insert my USB storage into my computer and it will not mount. I can see the USB drive recognised in KDE's panel, but it will not be mounted. I can click on the "mount" button in the panel, but nothing happens. If I remove the device and reconnect, always mounts the second time.

I looked through `sudo journalctl` for the relevant log lines, and there were two differences. Firstly, the failed mounting had the additional lines:

```
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

Secondly (perhaps unimportant), the failed mounting did `mtp-probe` before the kernel detected the USB mass storage device; this order was inverted when it worked.

The full log is reproduced below. This represents a failed connection, a disconnection, and a working connection. How can I make my USB device be mounted on the first connection?

I am using Arch Linux, but I also experienced this (I think) when I was using Kubuntu.

```
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5109]: checking bus 4, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2"
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5109]: bus: 4, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Mar 04 14:35:35 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB Flash Memory PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 15240576 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable")
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Part
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Blo
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block")
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 systemd-udevd[212]: error opening USB device 'descriptors' file
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi host7: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5198]: checking bus 4, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2"
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5198]: bus: 4, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Mar 04 14:35:44 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB Flash Memory PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 15240576 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable")
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Part
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 udisksd[554]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /run/media/lee/Lee-key on behalf of uid 1000
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[420]: index_parse.c:190: indx_parse(): error opening /run/media/lee/Lee-key/BDMV/index.bdmv
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[420]: index_parse.c:190: indx_parse(): error opening /run/media/lee/Lee-key/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: true "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 polkitd[416]: Operator of unix-session:c2 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount for system-bus-name::1.258 [kdeinit4: kded4 [
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5109]: checking bus 4, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2"
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5109]: bus: 4, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Mar 04 14:35:34 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Mar 04 14:35:35 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB Flash Memory PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 15240576 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable")
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Part
Mar 04 14:35:36 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Blo
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block")
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: Found removable storage volume for Baloo undocking: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:39 sparhawk-XPS-17 systemd-udevd[212]: error opening USB device 'descriptors' file
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb 4-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi host7: usb-storage 4-1.2:1.0
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5198]: checking bus 4, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2"
Mar 04 14:35:43 sparhawk-XPS-17 mtp-probe[5198]: bus: 4, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Mar 04 14:35:44 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB Flash Memory PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 15240576 512-byte logical blocks: (7.80 GB/7.26 GiB)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive")
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/USB_Flash_Memory_00187D0F56A0EE214000ABF8"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable")
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::accessibilityChanged(bool,QString) to Baloo::StorageDevices::slotAccessibilityChanged(bool,QString)
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Part
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 udisksd[554]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /run/media/lee/Lee-key on behalf of uid 1000
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[420]: index_parse.c:190: indx_parse(): error opening /run/media/lee/Lee-key/BDMV/index.bdmv
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[420]: index_parse.c:190: indx_parse(): error opening /run/media/lee/Lee-key/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 baloo_file[640]: true "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1"
Mar 04 14:35:45 sparhawk-XPS-17 polkitd[416]: Operator of unix-session:c2 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount for system-bus-name::1.258 [kdeinit4: kded4 [
```